# get code review tasks to display in dashboard in JIRA, assigned to me widget or similar

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Does anyone know how I might get Code review items to pop up on a jira dashboard.  I've tried various queries and different widgets (only one I can find from crucible), but alas I can't seem to find a way to get these to show up without having to navigate to that particular section.

*** just to clarify, this is more of a configuration of a jira install hosted by Atlassian.  They have widgets you can drag and drop onto a dashboard.  The the fisheye+crucible stuff allows you to create code reviews which seem to not pop into the jira stuff.

I'm sure there is a way though.

Comment: What have you done so far? show us some code.

Comment: well there really isn't any code to show, this stuff is drag and drop widgets on a jira install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like there is a widget that provides this functionality but apparently it is not available with the online versions of this application.  Moreover, crucible and the code review stuff, along with SVN support, is being dropped.